# Erro ao atualizar script PHP para a nova versão (MySQLI)

Tags: php, mysqli

Este script é utilizado conjuntamente ao Coppermine Gallery para mostrar os últimos álbuns criados na galeria. No entanto, ele parece não funcionar com o PHP 7.
Quando mantidas as strings com o formato antigo (mysql_connect), o erro dado é o seguinte:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/gustavoj/public_html/lauramarano.com.br/galeria/api.php:8
>   Stack trace:
>   0 {main}
>     thrown in **/home/gustavoj/public_html/lauramarano.com.br/galeria/api.php** on line **8**

E quando alteradas para mysqli_connect, eis que o erro é o seguinte:

> **Warning**:  mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in **/home/gustavoj/public_html/lauramarano.com.br/galeria/api.php** on line **10**
>   Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados

A minha dúvida é, qual é a melhor forma de atualizar esse script. E se há uma forma de atualizar esse script, pois ele é incrível e ajuda muito no desenvolvimeto front-end. Segue o código do script.

```
<?php
require_once('include/config.inc.php');
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");



$connect = mysqli_connect($CONFIG['dbserver'],$CONFIG['dbuser'],$CONFIG['dbpass'])
    or die('Erro ao conectar ao servidor');
$connect_db = mysqli_select_db($CONFIG['dbname'], $connect)
    or die ('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');


            $resultado = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_albums` ORDER BY `cpg_albums`.`aid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 12", $link)

                or die('Nenhum album encontrado com esta query');

                echo 'document.write(\'';

                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0){
                    echo 'Nenhum álbum cadastrado';
                } else { echo '<div id="postsgall">  ';
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
                        echo ' ';
                            $album_id = $row['aid'];
                            $subresult = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_pictures` where aid=$album_id order by pid DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

                            if(mysqli_num_rows($subresult) == 0){
                                $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/images/thumbs/thumb_nopic.png";
                            } else {
                                while($subrow = mysqli_fetch_array($subresult)){
                                    $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/albums/".$subrow['filepath'].'normal_'.$subrow['filename']  .$subrow['datebrowse'];

                                }
                            }

                            echo '<div><div class="postsg1"><div class="title">'.$row['title'].' </div><a href="http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/thumbnails.php?album='.$album_id.' "><img src="http://lauramarano.com.br/wp-content/themes/lmbr16/timthumb.php?src='.$album_img.'&w=164&h=223&zc=1" alt="" /></a> </div></div>';  

                        echo '';
                    }
                } echo '</tr></div>';
                echo '\');';

        ?>
```

Comment: Isso porque os parâmetros estão invertidos! [mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que não considera usar o PDO? Pdo seria uma das melhores opções para banco em PHP, ele é orientado a objetos e tem diversas opções de segurança. De uma olhada: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php

Agora respondendo sua questão tem diversos erros ai, não é simplesmente mudar de mysql para mysqli e todas as funções irão funcionar... Existem algumas restrições, estarei deixando comentarios de melhorias e consertos. 
Peço que indente seu código também para ficar mais fácil das próximas vezes, se não vão bater o olho e nem querer analisar.

```
<?php
require_once('include/config.inc.php');
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");


//Você já pode passar a db direto aqui
$connect = mysqli_connect($CONFIG['dbserver'], $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass'], $CONFIG['dbname']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Falha ao conectar: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//Na execução da query é necessário passar a conexão como primeiro parametro
$resultado = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cpg_albums` ORDER BY `cpg_albums`.`aid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 12");

echo 'document.write(\'';

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0) {
    echo 'Nenhum álbum cadastrado';
} else {
    echo '<div id="postsgall">  ';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo ' ';
        $album_id  = $row['aid'];
        $subresult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `cpg_pictures` where aid=$album_id order by pid DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($subresult) == 0) {
            $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/images/thumbs/thumb_nopic.png";
        } else {
            while ($subrow = mysqli_fetch_array($subresult)) {
                $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/albums/" . $subrow['filepath'] . 'normal_' . $subrow['filename'] . $subrow['datebrowse'];

            }
        }

        echo '<div><div class="postsg1"><div class="title">' . $row['title'] . ' </div><a href="http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=' . $album_id . ' "><img src="http://lauramarano.com.br/wp-content/themes/lmbr16/timthumb.php?src=' . $album_img . '&w=164&h=223&zc=1" alt="" /></a> </div></div>';

        echo '';
    }
}
echo '</tr></div>';
echo '\');';

?>
```

Também estarei deixando o método com PDO caso queira usar

```
<?php
    try{
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$CONFIG['dbserver'];dbname=$CONFIG['dbname']", $CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);
        //Seta o modo do erro do PDO para excessão
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_albums` ORDER BY `cpg_albums`.`aid` DESC LIMIT 0 , 12")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo 'document.write(\'';

        if (count($data) == 0) {
            echo 'Nenhum álbum cadastrado';
        } else {
            echo '<div id="postsgall">  ';
            while ($data as $row) {
                echo ' ';
                $album_id  = $row['aid'];
                $subresult = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `cpg_pictures` where aid=$album_id order by pid DESC LIMIT 0, 20")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if (count($subresult) == 0) {
                    $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/images/thumbs/thumb_nopic.png";
                } else {
                    while ($subresult as $subrow) {
                        $album_img = "http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/albums/" . $subrow['filepath'] . 'normal_' . $subrow['filename'] . $subrow['datebrowse'];

                    }
                }

                echo '<div><div class="postsg1"><div class="title">' . $row['title'] . ' </div><a href="http://lauramarano.com.br/galeria/thumbnails.php?album=' . $album_id . ' "><img src="http://lauramarano.com.br/wp-content/themes/lmbr16/timthumb.php?src=' . $album_img . '&w=164&h=223&zc=1" alt="" /></a> </div></div>';

                echo '';
            }
        }
        echo '</tr></div>';
        echo '\');';



    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mantive o código antigo, pois no seu ele não conseguia chegar até as imagens. Então usei a forma como você chamou a db, mas usei o código antigo para chamar as imagens. Bastou adicionar um $connect antes de especificar o nome do item dentro da db, e voila! (Se quiser ver o script funcionando, veja aqui https://bit.ly/2MNxC2k). Obrigado!